# Messages from console.log are invisible in Reactotron, the React Native debugger

Tags: react-native

I'm using Reactotron when I debug my react-native app.
How can I get `console.log` messages to be displayed?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways.

The first is to import `reactotron-react-native` in the files you want to send log to reactotron. Then use log, warn, error, display methods from the library. The detail info can be found [here](https://github.com/infinitered/reactotron/blob/master/docs/quick-start-react-native.md#hello-world).

```js
import Reactotron from 'reactotron-react-native'

... your code

Reactotron.log({ data: [1,2,3] })
```

The second way is to define global variable for reactotron. This can be done in the reactotron configuration file `ReactotronConfig.js`.

```js
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import reactotron from 'reactotron-react-native';

const tron = reactotron
  .setAsyncStorageHandler(AsyncStorage)
  .configure()
  .useReactNative()
  .connect();

console.tron = tron;
```

Then you can use `console.tron.log({ data: [1,2,3] })` anywhere in your code without needing to import `reactotron-react-native` again and again.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `console.tron.log('Hello, Martin');` does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Reactotron api provides a direct option to console the logs

First

> import Reactotron from 'reactotron-react-native';

then

> Reactotron.log('test.', value);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).